# How to run some native code , while developing on PhoneGap/Cordova?

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, push-notification, mpns

I am developing a PhoneGap/Cordova WP7 application.

I need for this application , to have push notifications enabled however there is NO plugin for this yet.

I wrote the code "native" in C# , for registering to my server for push etc etc.

Now i want to use this code in my PhoneGap/Cordova project. Can i make this part of code run , without having to make a custom plugin for it?

If not can anyone help me on how to make a plugin for it? I have all the native code complete which is less than 50 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a plugin to use the push notification code for phonegap application.

[Link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_windows-phone_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Windows%20Phone) to the official plugin dev guide for windows phone using phonegap.